# How To Write A Plugin that triggers when a related Sub-grid is updated

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am creating a plugin that is supposed to trigger when a **new record is added in a sub-grid (contractdetail) on form for the contract entity**. There is a 1-N relationship between contract and contractdetail (contract_line_items). I only want my plugin to execute if the contract entity is active (statecode == 0).. I just want to update some records based on that, however, I cannot get the plugin to execute based on the criteria that I want. Here is what I have so far:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;


/// <summary>
/// This plugin will update Unit Orders after the contract has already been invoiced.
/// The update will run on the alter unit orders.
/// </summary>

namespace MAGA.Plugins
{


    [CrmPluginRegistration(MessageNameEnum.Update,
    "contractdetail",
    StageEnum.PostOperation,
    ExecutionModeEnum.Asynchronous,
    "contractid",
    "Post-Invoice Contract",
    1000,
    IsolationModeEnum.Sandbox,
    Image1Name = "PreImage",
    Image1Type = ImageTypeEnum.PreImage,
    Image1Attributes = "")]
    public class UnitPluginPostInvoice : IPlugin
    {

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
            // Will be registering this plugin, thus will need to add tracing service related code.

            ITracingService tracing = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            //obtain execution context from service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            // InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request. 
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                Entity PreImage = context.PreEntityImages["PreIMage"];



                if (entity.LogicalName != "contractdetail" && entity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value != 0)
                    return;


                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                    (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);


                var contractId = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("contractid");
                var contract = service.Retrieve(contractId.LogicalName, contractId.Id, new ColumnSet(true));

                if (contract.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value != 0)
                    return;

                try
                {
                    // Plugin code here
                }
                catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occured.. Phil is responsible. ", ex);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracing.Trace("An error occured: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Here is a picture for a visual reference!

[image: Contract Form]

Comment: Is it not triggering at all? I don’t see Associate message for both entities in documentation. Also I don’t think someone can add contractdetail for an inactive contract, (+) button will not be shown.

Comment: No, I only need it to trigger if the contract is invoiced. Its supposed to update records in another entity not shown here (called unit orders). When a contract is made, unit orders are made for it when it's invoiced, however, contract lines can be added later on (after contract invoice). When a new contract line is made, it needs to update the Unit Orders!

Comment: I can add contract lines after invoice... The contract shown above has been invoiced. The plugin is supposed to trigger when a new contract line is added. Like I said its going to have to update existing records in another entity called Unit Orders.

Comment: Shouldn't I be using Update message instead of Associate since the relationship is 1 to many?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments on the code:

- The plugin is async. Unless you are communicating with a web service, you should switch to sync. It also gives a better feedback to the user.
- The event is Update (MessageNameEnum.Update), it should only be create in this case
- When you fetch the contract status change this: new ColumnSet(true) for this: new ColumnSet("statecode"). true means return all columns.
- Englobe everything in the try-catch.

The rest looks good. Good luck and says hi to Phil for me.

Comment: As usual, you are a life saver!!